# Regex invalid URL, what is wrong with my regex rule?

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex rule for website urls.
I'm not sure why the following is not working with my regex rule.
Can someone help here?

Regex:

```
$regex = '/^(?:https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?)?[a-z0-9]+(?:[-.][a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,}(?::[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/';
```

Invalid URL format:

```
https://game.game123.io?r=235ffw12105gawfwara2332FWWF66e1EA9121685aa
```

Comment: I don't get an error, it just doesn't match.

Comment: Your regexp doesn't match URLs with `?` in them.

Comment: There is no `/` so the last part does not match until the end of the string, see https://regex101.com/r/mGcgb0/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird The last part is optional because of `?`

Comment: It also won't match URLs with `#` in them.

Comment: @Barmar Yes it is, then match either a `/` or `?` or `#` I think like https://regex101.com/r/UK5qvS/1

Answer (score 1):

First of all thanks for all answers, the following 2 rules work, i just wonder which syntax is better since they seem to do the same?

regex 1

```
^(?:https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?)?[a-z0-9]+(?:[-.][a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,}(?::[0-9]{1,5})?([?\/#].*)?$
```

regex 2

```
^(?:https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?)?[a-z0-9]+(?:[-.][a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,}(?::[0-9]{1,5})?(?:[?\/#].*)?$
```

Is the additional ?: before [?/#] in syntax 2 required or not?

Answer (score 0):

The pattern matches repetitions of either `.` or `-` followed by `[a-z0-9]+`.

The full string does not match as there is a question mark in `?r=`, but the pattern expects a leading `/` in the optional part at the end.

What you might do is match any of the character that you would allow using a character class `[?/#]` in the last optional part followed by the rest of the line.

```
^(?:https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?)?[a-z0-9]+(?:[-.][a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,}(?::[0-9]{1,5})?(?:[?/#].*)?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?)?` Optionally match the protocol and optional `www.`
- `[a-z0-9]+` Match 1+ a char a-z or digit 0-9
- `(?:[-.][a-z0-9]+)*` Optionally repeat either `-` or `.` and match 1+ times a char a-z or a digit 0-9
- `\.[a-z]{2,}` Match a `.` and 2 or more times a char a-z
- `(?::[0-9]{1,5})?` Optionally match `:` and 1-5 digits 0-9
- `(?:[?/#].*)?` Optionally match either `?` `/` or `#`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6O2hz0/1)